# In Rails 5, how do I inherit from a module I have defined?

Tags: inheritance, module, ruby-on-rails-5, base-class

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.  I have created this base class in lib/audit/top_level_service.rb

```
module Audit::Services
  class TopLevelService
    ...
  end
end
```

In another part of my application, app/services/accounting_service.rb, I would like to inherit from this module I created above, so I tried

```
class AccountingService < Audit::Services::TopLevelService
...
end
```

but this results in an "uninitialized constant Audit::Services" error.  What's the right way to reference my base class from my normal class definition?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). When you try to access `PerkspotService` it doesn't have `Audit::Services` and there is no file `audit/services.rb`. There are multiple ways you can try to solve it. You can predefine namespaces in `application.rb` like this:

```rb
Audit = Module.new
Audit::Services = Module.new
```

You can try to wrap `PerkspotService` in a namespace like:

```rb
module Audit::Services
  class PerkspotService < TopLevelService
  ...
  end
end
```

Lastly and the arguably correct way to do this is to follow rules described in a link provided. You'll need to match file path to definition name. So you `Audit::Services::TopLevelService` needs to be a file named: `audit/services/top_level_service.rb` in one of the autoloading folders.

Comment: Hi @Igor, regarding your "module Audit::Services ..." class, what is the path to that?  I tried "app/services/accounting_service.rb" but am getting the error, "`load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant CSV::BaseService" when I start my rails app or console.  (also sorry for the rename, the class name that shoudl inherit from "TopLevelService" is actually named "AccountingService")

Comment: Path will be: `app/services/audit/services/accounting_service.rb`. You can think of `app/services` or any other as a root and rest should follow your name. It's most likely will solve second problem. but if it's not you need to use `::BaseService`, `::` in the beginning will say to use top level scope. Otherwise it tries to lookup constant within current class/module (like absolute/relative paths).

Answer (score 0):

Just define it the  *right way* instead.

```
# lib/audit/services/top_level_service.rb
module Audit
  module Services
    class TopLevelService
    end
  end
end
```

Do not use the scope resolution operator `::` when defining modules or classes! It does not create the correct module nesting and the results can be very suprising. The nesting inside TopLevelService would actually be `::Audit` instead of `::Audit::Services`. It will also blow up if `Audit::Services` has not yet been loaded.

Placing it at `lib/audit/services/top_level_service.rb` lets the autoloader just load the file provided `lib` is in the autoload paths.

Comment: Thanks @max, but how would I structure things if I wanted my file path to be "app/services/top_level_service.rb" and not "lib/audit/services/top_level_service.rb"?

Comment: You would have to place the file in `app/services/audit/services/top_level_service.rb`. I would just place it in `app/audit/services/top_level_service.rb` instead. Don't fight the autoloader - it will just make your code harder to find for other developers.

Comment: Putting this class in `app/services/top_level_service.rb` is a pretty blatant violation of the principle of least suprise.